# setting 'minWidth' default config for button in ext js 4

Tags: extjs, extjs4

i'm currently trying to get my head around the theming capabilities of ext js 4 and am having some trouble with the styling of buttons.

setting button dimensions isn't quite possible using the scss variables provided, but there are some javascript config options for this. as i don't want to have to apply these settings to every button instance, i was looking for a way of setting 'config defaults' for the button class.

the following approach worked out well when setting a default height:

```
Ext.button.Button.prototype.height = 15;
```

unfortunately, this seems not to be possible for the 'minWidth' config:

```
Ext.button.Button.prototype.minWidth = 1; //nope, sorry
```

is there a way of setting a default value for 'minWidth'?

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740388/button-width-in-extjs maybe it helps

Comment: thanks, but that's all about ext 3, and the generated button seems to be completely different in ext 4 - i.e. no more tables :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### short answer

```
Ext.override(Ext.panel.Panel, {
    minButtonWidth: 1
});
Ext.override(Ext.button.Button, {
    minWidth: 1
});
```

### longer answer

setting `Ext.button.Button.prototype.minWidth = 1;` is correct (better use the override mentioned in the short answer), but ignored by ExtJs internal handling of setting the default minWidth of 75 of `Ext.panel.Panel` (see `bridgeToolbars()` function). So if you would use a button outside of a Panel Toolbar, your initial try would work.

Also, there is a hardcoded minWidth of 75 of buttons in the `makeButtons()` function of `Ext.window.MessageBox`.

In my opinion you should open a bugreport @sencha, because there should be a themable, more global setting for this.

update: this was tested with ExtJS 4.1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change it for every single button with in the framework. Use the override system.

**app/overrides/Button.js**

```
Ext.define('App.overrides.Button', {}, function() {
    Ext.override(Ext.button.Button, {
        minWidth: 20
    });
});
```

**app.js**

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    /*
     * Load Overrides
     */
    Ext.require([
        'App.overrides.Button'
    ]);
});

var app = Ext.Application({.....
```

I'm not sure how sensible this is however as things like tabs extend from button and it might have some adverse effects. But thats how it's done any how.

Comment: Tried it on my setup here and it worked fine. The only thing I've missed out is how I apply my overrides. I'll update the answer to show how.

Comment: this answer is correct, if you don't render your button inside a `Ext.panel.Panel`or a `Ext.window.MessageBox`. Please see my answer for a solution.

Comment: +1 for providing a viable solution, but return1.at got my edge case right :)